# Density in histogram doesn't show completely

Tags: probability-or-statistics, histograms

```
data = RandomVariate[BetaDistribution[1, 3], 1000];
plot = Show[
  Histogram[data, Automatic, "PDF", PlotLabel -> "\[Gamma]", 
   GridLines -> {{{Mean[data], Directive[Opacity[1], Thick, Blue]}}, 
     None}, Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}], 
  Plot[PDF[GammaDistribution[0.25, 0.1], x], {x, 0.001, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

The histogram we obtain, is [image]

I think the problem is that the gamma density increases very rapidly as we come closer to zero. Is there a way to somehow solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to add some `PlotRange`, e.g.:

```
plot = Show[
Histogram[data, Automatic, "PDF", PlotLabel -> "\[Gamma]", 
GridLines -> {{{Mean[data], Directive[Opacity[1], Thick, Blue]}},None},
Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}], 
Plot[PDF[GammaDistribution[0.25, 0.1], x], {x, 0.001, 1}, 
PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> {{0, 0.9}, {0, 4}}]]
```

Which results to a plot such as this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks partial ;) +1

Answer (score 2):

You can also add `PlotRange -> All` to `Plot` and `PlotRange -> Automatic` to `Show` to get

```
Show[
  Histogram[data, Automatic, "PDF", PlotLabel -> "γ", 
     GridLines -> {{{Mean[data], Directive[Opacity[1], Thick, Blue]}},  None}, 
     Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}], 
  Plot[PDF[GammaDistribution[0.25, 0.1], x], {x, 0.001, 1}, 
    PlotStyle -> Red, 
    PlotRange -> All], 
  PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks kglr ;) +1